# Verify the code that was sent by SMS using twilio

Tags: c#, sms, twilio-api

I need to go from free to paid trial in Twilio so that it sends the SMS with the code to verify the number that the user entered, since in the free trial it is only sent to a specific number that was entered in the free trial but I need that when a user enters his number, the code arrives at his mobile number and thus verify his mobile number in my application, they told me that I have to buy a number in Twilio but I have no more steps to follow if I already bought the number that I have to do after I already bought the number on Twilio, I hope you can help me and have made me understand.

My code is made in xamari forms c#

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are trying to send a verification code to mobile numbers using C#, right?

In this case, I have good news. You don't need a phone number at all and can directly use the [Twilio Verify service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/quickstarts/csharp-asp-net-core-mvc):

```cs
// Install the C# / .NET helper library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install

using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Verify.V2.Service;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
        string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
        string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var verification = VerificationResource.Create(
            to: "+15017122661",
            channel: "sms",
            pathServiceSid: "VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        );

        Console.WriteLine(verification.Status);
    }
}
```

For completion, it is also possible to implement this on your own by [buying more numbers](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135247-How-to-Search-for-and-Buy-a-Twilio-Phone-Number-from-Console) and sending messages with them. But this approach can lead to multiple pitfalls that the Verify service already takes care of that, such as:

- Procuring international numbers
- Handle high throughput
- Offering other channels such as WhatsApp or Voice
- [SMS Traffic Pumping Fraud](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/8360406023067-SMS-Traffic-Pumping-Fraud)
- Storing the codes you sent out
- Manage expiration of codes
- and more

Comment: Exactly, I want a random code to be generated and sent to the cell phone numbers that users enter, but without the need for me to send it, I need it to be done by itself.

Comment: While technically you could do this from a Xamarin Forms (XF) app, doing this type of security verification on the client side is not safe. You need to run your verification server side. So your best option is to host an ASP.NET Core application with a Web API that'll run the verification code that @IObert shared. You can then communicate with that API from your XF app. When the phone number is verified, you can run the necessary server side code as you wish to mark the user's phone number as verified.